# Quotation Marks in Caption result in \

Tags: latex, caption

I am using the `caption`and `sub caption`package.
When using text with Quotation Marks in the Caption like this:

```
\caption{my name is "`Earl"'}
```

The caption under the picture says

```
my name is „Earl\
```

where does the backslash `\`come from? In the rest of the text, the Quotation Marks with `"` and `"'` work perfectly for `lower` and `upper` Quotation marks.

Here's is an example

```
\caption[This is the short caption of my category "`All Clouds on Earth"']{This is the long caption for the graphic of my category "`All Clouds on Earth"'. As you can see, all clouds are white}
```

Instead of `„All Clouds on Earth"` The Caption says `„All Clouds on Earth\`
However i figured that if I used `"`in the caption it works ...
Example:

```
\caption[This is the short caption of my category "`All Clouds on Earth"]{This is the long caption for the graphic of my category "`All Clouds on Earth". As you can see, all clouds are white}
```

This gets me what i wanted `„All Clouds on Earth"` 
It just kinda sucks that i have to use different methods for `"` in the text and in the captions, and I'm pretty sure that there's a better way but for now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay for the reason that I have not enough reputation to comment, I will write it as an answer:

First of all I don't know why the `\` appears, it doesn't happen to me, but maybe this helps fixing your problem:

For quotation marks, you can also write this:

```
\caption{my name is \glqq Earl\grqq }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I tried this but It did not work, It works in the Text without any problems but not within the caption ... I always end put with \ as last Quotation mark

Comment: Okay I tried to find the error but it works fine for me, could you edit your question and post your complete preamble and the stuff around the caption please?